# How can I generate a random number which will not be generated again afterwards?

Tags: python, random

I'd like to create a program which will generate random numbers between 1 and 30 until all numbers have been generated once. Essentially, I want to generate random numbers which will never be generated again afterwards.

```
import random
test = random.randint(1, 30)
```

This is what I have so far, but of course, a number already generated will be generated again.

Comment: Ah yes, this is what I need. I couldn't see it on the suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generate a list of 29 numbers (second argument) from given list (first argument). Note that you will get error if second argument is bigger than size of first argument.

```
import random
randoms = random.sample(range(1, 30), 29)
print(randoms)
```

Comment: So would this print them all at once?

Comment: Yes but you can also iterate them and print them one by one or use them however you need.

Comment: If I only had 1 number generated, how could I assign it to a variable?

Comment: I guess `one_random_number = randoms[0]` would do that.

Comment: You know that `30` is not included in `range(1, 30)`?

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want repeated numbers:

```
l = []
while len(set(l)) < 30:
    l.append(random.randint(1, 30))
print('\n'.join(map(str, l)))
```